# R2HTML number formatting

Tags: r, r2html

I want to output a dataframe using R2HTML, and remove scientific notation. Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the format command:

```
format(c(1,10,100)^3, scientific=FALSE)
```

Incidentally, I would recommend using `xtable` for the table itself.  See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407680/how-can-i-produce-report-quality-tables-from-r).

Comment: i took your advice and am using xtable, although i wish it used thead and tbody (javascript purposes). Also thanks on the format though it turns out I had to ditch this fomrat in order to use formatC and put in commas.